# Ajax long polling - 30 seconds each

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I have implement the exact same concept for my project-

http://blog.perplexedlabs.com/2009/05/04/php-jquery-ajax-javascript-long-polling/

My question is, will it work for 100 concurrent users.

Thanks
Anubhav

Comment: It depends on too many things to give an answer. Have you tried running the load tester 'ab' on your system?

Comment: If you buy a beefy enough server with enough bandwidth, it will work for a million concurrent users. Whether it will work for your specific app on your specific server at your specific hosting is a matter for testing...

Comment: No I have not tested it on load tester, but I will definately share the results. What else will matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your current backend.

What server (how many ?), operating system, database are you using ? Are you hosted on a shared server or a dedicated server (or even VPS) ?

Do you have more information about your current setup ?

Comment: Right now I am testing it on LAN, I am planning to purchase hosting for it. Linux, MySql, VPS (I think will be good option not sure)

Comment: Depending on how memory your VPS will have, you might consider taking two seperate VPS, one for your webserver and PHP instance, and the other one for your database. If everything is configured properly, it should work flawlessy. Also, take a look at PostgreSQL. From what I have experienced, it is more memory friendly (when it is properly configured) and it runs  perfectly on my VPS.